# Cefsharp throwing an error in console application in vs 2019

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2019, console-application, cefsharp

I have a VS 2019 solution that has a console application and WinForms application.

I have added cefsharp in WindowsFormApp using Package Manager. I try to build the entire solution but get an error. I have not added any code to my solution/applications.

Error:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1513  } expected  Test    F:\Learning\TradingDetails\03012024\Test\packages\CefSharp.Common.120.2.50\src\CefSharp\Internals\Partial\ChromiumWebBrowser.Partial.cs 18  Active
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1022  Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected   Test    F:\Learning\TradingDetails\03012024\Test\packages\CefSharp.Common.120.2.50\src\CefSharp\Internals\Partial\ChromiumWebBrowser.Partial.cs 541 Active

Winforms application builds and runs without any issues. Console application is not building/running because of this error. Please advice.

Comment: Insufficient information to know what's going on. Somehow you've included source file from the package into your project. There's working examples provided at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample

Comment: @amaitland I didnot touch the code. I just added the package via Nuget. It automatically gets added to the other project (console application) in the same solution.

Comment: I've never seen this behaviour, nor do I remember any other reports. You need to provide more information. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example